How to calculate the Chern Number in real-space numerically by using non-commutative Chern Number (NCCN)?
We all know that the formula of real space in given by:

where: 
and P is the projection operator of occupied states on the basis of real space.
My question is:
(1) How to due with the position operator in that formula?
(2) How to calculate real space chern number numerically by using matlab or python?
